# CasperJS/PhantomJS Cookie Handling

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, screen-scraping, casperjs

When I visit this site in a browser I get the google.com tracking cookies:

```
http://www.xfinityonline.com/
```

However, I don't see these cookies when I visit the site in CasperJS (I do see other third-party cookies). Any idea why this is happening?

I am using phantomjs 1.9.7 and casperjs 1.1.0-beta3. I am capturing `resource.requested` and `resource.received` to verify that the google.com resource is being loaded. I am dumping `phantom.cookies` to verify that the cookies are not set. I am using FireBug to test with a live browser.

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I am using phantomjs 1.9.7 and casperjs 1.1.0-beta3. I am capturing resource.requested and resource.received to verify that the google.com resource is being loaded. I am dumping phantom.cookies to verify that the cookies are not set. I am using FireBug to test with a live browser.